# Extracting SVG HTML paths back to SVG files from a website

Tags: html, svg, vector, vector-graphics

Is there any way to quickly extract SVG assets on a website including SVG HTML paths back to SVG files. Any apps, dev tools, extensions that lets you do this?

Answer (score 42):

Given an `svg` element you'd like to save:

## Edge

1. Right Click **>** Save Picture As

## Chrome, Firefox, etc.

1. Inspect Element (*Make sure you've selected the root `svg` element you'd like to save*).
2. Right Click **>** Edit as HTML
3. Copy the outer HTML
4. Paste in your favorite text editor (*VS Code*), and save as a `.svg`

Comment: bonus step if you want a lighter optimized svg file:paste the markup in https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, have a look at [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

Just copy-paste the `d` parameter from an HTML page and click "Downaload as SVG" button